# How can I organize a list keeping the minimum similarity between adjacent elements from a similarity matrix?

Tags: r, sorting, math, similarity, algebra

I have a list of 24 samples. For each sample I have a vector with the distances to the other samples. This constitutes a 24 by 24 similarity matrix. In this matrix the similarity values range from 0 to 100, where 100 is the similarity value of a sample to itself.

Here's An image of the similarity matrix (with dendrogram) and a subset of the matrix

[image: HeatMap + dendrogram]

```
> similarity_matrix[1:10,1:10]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  100   10   15    0   15   50   25   10   25    10
 [2,]   10  100    0   20    0   30   10   30   50    70
 [3,]   15    0  100    0   15    0   15    0   15     0
 [4,]    0   20    0  100   50   20    0   20    0    20
 [5,]   15    0   15   50  100    0   15    0   15     0
 [6,]   50   30    0   20    0  100   10   30   10    30
 [7,]   25   10   15    0   15   10  100   50   25    10
 [8,]   10   30    0   20    0   30   50  100   10    30
 [9,]   25   50   15    0   15   10   25   10  100    50
[10,]   10   70    0   20    0   30   10   30   50   100
```

From this similarity matrix and choosing a starting sample I would like to be able to generate a list that minimises the similarity of a sample to its two adjacent samples.

So far I have not been able to think of an efficient way to do this. Either through mathematical operations or using loops.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know R but im guessing you could do just loop the first index of the matrix and get the simularitys to the value befor and after it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < row.count; i++)
{
   leftIndex = i - 1;
   rightIndex = i + 1;
   totalCost = 0;
   if (leftIndex >= 1)
   {
      totalCost += matrix[i][leftIndex]
   }
   if (rightIndex < column.count)
   {
       totalCost += matrix[i][leftIndex]
   }     
    list.add(totalCost)
}
```

After that you just need to sort the values while keeping track of what index got that value.